# A recursive function that determines whether the digits of a number are in ascending order

Tags: c, recursion

I'm practicing recursion and my solution to the problem doesn't seem to work.
I'm trying to write a recursive code that will determine if the digits of a number are in ascending order or not. here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isAscending(int num);
int main(){
    int result;
    result = isAscending(123);//Should print "The number is in ascending order!"
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("The number is in ascending order!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The number is not in ascending order!\n");
    }
}
int isAscending(int num) {
    int new = num / 10;
    int result = 0;
    if ((num % 10) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((num % 10) > (new % 10)) {
        result += isAscending(num / 10);
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So. What does it mean "doesn't seem to work"? And why are you terminating if a digit is `0`?

Comment: usually recursive functions call themselves.  I don't see that in your `isAscending(...)`

Comment: Also, why are you *adding* the result?

Comment: I changed the name of the function before posting it here and forgot to change the name in the code, I fixed it now:)

Comment: Can you write down the recursive rule for your logic? This is the best way to start writing recursion.

Comment: because at the end of the recursion, if the digits are in ascending order I want that isAscending will return 0- there were not digits that are bigger than the digits before

Comment: Is `112233` ascending per your code goal?  How about `-123`.  You only have 1 example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another (bare-bones) way to go about it. The basic idea is that if we have a single digit, we return affirmative, else we check if the rightmost number is greater than the one just to it's left. And we do this for the remaining digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isAsc(int i)
{
    int rem = i % 10;    // remainder
    int quo = i / 10;    // quotient

    if (rem == i)
        return 1;
    else if (rem <= (quo % 10))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 && isAsc(quo);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 123123;
    if (isAsc(i))
        printf("%s\n", "Ascending");
    else
        printf("%s\n", "Not ascending");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `isAsc(-123)` returns 0.  Unclear how OP wants to handle negative values.

Comment: Could simplify `return 1 && isAsc(quo);` --> `return isAsc(quo);`

Comment: @chux Yea, I couldn't figure out what to do with negative values hence "bare-bones" :). Yes, it could be simplified, but kinda like thinking that all the results are being run through `&&` and the final result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below recurrsive code:

`

```
boolean isascending(int num){

if(num == 0) return true;
if(num%10>num%100) return isascending(num/10);
else return false;
}`
```

or you can use while loop:

```
while(num>0){
if(num%10 > num%100){
   num = num/10;
   continue;
} return false;
} return true;
```

Comment: The OP tagged this question as `C`. Your program is not complete / will not run as is.

Comment: Both failed various tests.  You may want to review/test.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use another parameter to store the last digit, which is going to be "dropped" in the current iteration.

So I came up with the following recursive logic:

- use a parameter which stores the last digit dropped
- **base case**: if the number is 0, `return 0` (`true`)
- calculate the current last digit of the number (number%10)
- if the current last digit is greater than the last digit dropped: is this case, `return 1` (`false`)
- if not, return `isAscendingRecursive()` on the new number dropping the current last digit and pass it as the next iteration last digit.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** args){
    int num=0;
    printf("Insert a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(isAscending(num)==0)
        printf("Ascending\n");
    else
        printf("Not ascending\n");
}

int isAscending(int num){
    return isAscendingRecursive(num,9);
}

int isAscendingRecursive(int num, int lastDigit){
    if(num == 0)
        return 0;

    int temp = num%10;
    if(temp > lastDigit)
        return 1;
    else
        return isAscendingRecursive(num/10, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution returns 0 on failure otherwise some other integer on success.  It seems that isDescending() is easier to write when returning 0 as a failure value but I contorted this accordingly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isAscending(int num) {
    int quotient = num / 10;
    int remainder = num % 10;

    if (quotient != 0) {

        int result = isAscending(quotient);

        if (result == 0 || result >= remainder) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return remainder;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (isAscending(atoi(argv[1]))) {
        printf("The number is in ascending order!\n");
    } else {
        printf("The number is not in ascending order!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**TESTS**

```
% ./a.out 123
The number is in ascending order!
% ./a.out 321
The number is not in ascending order!
% ./a.out 101
The number is not in ascending order!
%
```

No, it doesn't handle negative numbers!  It also doesn't handle '0' correctly as an input -- other single digit numbers are fine.

Again, isDescending() is easier to write but unfortunately, !isDescending() != isAscending()

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are incorrect.  You should return true for numbers with a single digit, false if the last digit is less or equal to the previous one and recurse for the rest:

```
int isAscending(int num) {
    int new = num / 10;

    if (new == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else
    if (num % 10 <= new % 10) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return isAscending(new);
    }
}
```

This kind of recursion is called tail recursion as you return the result of the recursive call.  Good compilers will generate iterative code equivalent to this:

```
int isAscending(int num) {
    for (;;) {
        int new = num / 10;

        if (new == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (num % 10 <= new % 10) {
            return 0;
        }
        num = new;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed my code and it works, thanks for the help!:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isAscending(int num);
int main(){
    int result;
    result = isAscending(2589);//Should print "The number is in ascending order!"
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("The number is in ascending order!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The number is not in ascending order!\n");
    }
}
int isAscending(int num) {
    int new = num / 10;
    int result = 0;
    if ((num % 10) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((num % 10) > (new % 10)) {
        return isAscending(num / 10);
    }
    else {
       return 1 + isAscending(num / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer incorrectly reports `10, 20, 101, etc` is ascending.  Also `isAscending()` returns a zero when ascending which sounds backwards from the functions name.  `int result = 0;` serves no value.

Comment: Why do you return `0` for `0`?